# Customize font of icon property of Material UI Table when using text instead of icon

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using Material UI table in my react app and I want a custom event on the action button (instead of Add, Update or Delete). Rather than creating my own icon, I just want to have some text so I did...

```
<MaterialTable
                data={someData}
                actions= {[
                      {
                      icon: () => "My Custom Action",
                      iconProps: { style: { fontSize: "10px", color: "blue" } },
                      tooltip: "Search Transactions",
                      onClick: (event, rowData) => (
                          alert("You did a custom on action " + rowData)
                      )
                  }
```

Right now the text from the icon is huge and ugly as shown in the attached screenshot[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Any way to apply some styles to make it smaller and fit into the table?

I tried iconProps but it didn't do anything.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysht7.png

Answer (score 0):

You can add options and then create your styles in there.

```
options={{
        rowStyle: { fontSize: "10px", color: "blue" }
      }}
```

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling

Comment: Thanks @Travis, but this will apply to the entire row. I am looking to style only the 'action' icon text.